# libvpx and python-sqlalchemy causing errors when running `yay -Syyu`

Tags: arch-linux

My computer runs Arch Linux. I have `yay` installed.

Recently, when I run `yay -Syyu` I've been prompted with the following messages, and here are the responses I give. The result is basically the same, conflicting packages prevents the upgrades from running.

Below are the four outputs. How do I resolve these errors and get on with the system upgrade?

```
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace qwtpolar with extra/qwt? [Y/n] Y
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
warning: removing 'python-sqlalchemy' from target list because it conflicts with 'python-sqlalchemy1.3'
:: python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy are in conflict. Remove python-sqlalchemy? [y/N] y
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing libvpx (1.11.0-1) breaks dependency 'libvpx.so=6-64' required by ffmpeg-compat-57
 -> error installing repo packages


 :: Starting full system upgrade...
 :: Replace qwtpolar with extra/qwt? [Y/n] n
 resolving dependencies...
 looking for conflicting packages...
 warning: removing 'python-sqlalchemy' from target list because it conflicts with 'python-sqlalchemy1.3'
 :: python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy are in conflict. Remove python-sqlalchemy? [y/N] y
 error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
 :: installing libvpx (1.11.0-1) breaks dependency 'libvpx.so=6-64' required by ffmpeg-compat-57
  -> error installing repo packages



:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace qwtpolar with extra/qwt? [Y/n] Y
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
warning: removing 'python-sqlalchemy' from target list because it conflicts with 'python-sqlalchemy1.3'
:: python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy are in conflict. Remove python-sqlalchemy? [y/N] N
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy are in conflict
 -> error installing repo packages


:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace qwtpolar with extra/qwt? [Y/n] n
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
warning: removing 'python-sqlalchemy' from target list because it conflicts with 'python-sqlalchemy1.3'
:: python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy are in conflict. Remove python-sqlalchemy? [y/N] N
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy are in conflict
 -> error installing repo packages
```

Comment: Did you try to remove completely python-sqlalchemy1.3 and python-sqlalchemy and reinstall the version from your repo before doing the upgrade? (Note: I'm not an ArchLinux guy, so I may be completely out of subject...)

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 separate problems.

You should answer "y" to the first prompt and replace qwtpolar with extra/qwt.

The next issue is the package python-sqlalchemy1.3. Uninstall it manually, if some package needs it as a dependency uninstall it too and reinstall if after the update.

The last problem seems to be the package libvpx, that cannot be updated due to ffmpeg-compat-57 requiring a specific version of libvpx.

I searched for ffmpeg-compat-57 on the Arch Linux AUR, and I see [this (second comment by HurricanePootis)](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ffmpeg-compat-57/) is what people mention as the solution:

> I was able to solve my issues by uninstall ffmpeg-compat-57, updating ffmpeg, then rebuilding ffmpeg-compat-57.

So to summarise, to solve your problem:

1. Uninstall ffmpeg-compat-57 (if it is a dependency, remove the program requiring it as well.)
2. Run `yay -S ffmpeg` to update ffmpeg.
3. Reinstall ffmpeg-compat-57 or the program that needs it as a dependency.
4. Uninstall python-sqlalchemy1.3 (if it is a dependency, remove the program requiring it as well.)
5. Start the update with `yay -Syu`, no need to force refreshing of all the mirrors, pacman detects which need to be updated.
6. Answer 'y' on the prompt about replacing qwtpolar with extra/qwt.
7. Continue with update.
8. Reinstall python-sqlalchemy1.3 or the program that needs it as a dependency.